# Listing elements from top to bottom rather than horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, html-select

I am trying to list options on my page from top to bottom rather than left to right.

```
 return (
         <div className="quizChallenge">
           <WebHeader/>
           <h2 id = "description"> {this.state.quizzes.description}</h2>
           <ol>
           <table id="t01">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 {this.state.options.map((option) => {
                   return (
                     <td key={option}>
                       <button disabled={!this.state.optionEnabled} onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(this.state.options.indexOf(option))}>
                         {option}
                       </button></td>
                   );
                 })}
               </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
           </ol>
           {currentQuestion < 8 &&
                <button className="ui inverted button" disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={this.nextQuestion}>Next</button>
           }
           {currentQuestion === 7 &&
                <button className="ui inverted button" disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={this.lastQuestion}>Finish Quiz!</button>
           }
         </div>
       );
```

[image: The code above creates four buttons in one table row.]

Can someone assist me with the best way of doing this?

Comment: Check out flexbox, this should do the thing for you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp

Comment: wrap the `td` in the `return` with `tr` and remove `tr` which is outside the map function

Comment: Your HTML is malformed; the only [tags permitted within the ol element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) are `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<tr>
 {this.state.options.map((option) => {
   return (
     <td key={option}>
       <button disabled={!this.state.optionEnabled} onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(this.state.options.indexOf(option))}>
         {option}
       </button></td>
   );
 })}
</tr>
```

to

```
{this.state.options.map((option) => {
   return (
    <tr>
     <td key={option}>
       <button disabled={!this.state.optionEnabled} onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(this.state.options.indexOf(option))}>
         {option}
       </button>
     </td>
    <tr>
   );
 })}
```

**Explanation by Woodrow Barlow:** `tr` stands for "table row" and `td` for "table data". with multiple data cells in a single row, they display horizontally. With one data cell per row, they display vertically.

Comment: `tr` stands for "table row" and `td` for "table data". with multiple data cells in a single row, they display horizontally. with one data cell per row, they display vertically.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow thanks for the better explanation, I have used your explanation in the answer :)